# MySQL -How to locate a database on flash memory

Tags: mysql, flash-memory

i am new on MySQL with flash memory
i want to change the location of MySQL database and put it on flash memory instead of local machine
how to do that?? any help please

Comment: try this http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-change-the-mysql-data-default-directory.html

Comment: it doesn't works on windows..any similar code for windows?